# Code snippet not working inside a method call

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

I have a very simple snippet

Why do snippets not work inside methods calls when coding parameters?
e.g.

I have a very simple snippet:

```
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>CommonSnippets</Title>
      <Author>me</Author>
      <Description>
      </Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>newGuidAsString</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[Guid.NewGuid().ToString()]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
```

This works fine in the main body of code but when I want to use it to code the parameter of a method call.

e.g. I want the line

```
this.SetSomeValue(myObject, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

but when typing out the line snippets do not appear once inside the parentheses.

```
this.SetSomeValue(myObject, newG...
```

Is there any way to get a snippet to appear here?

Comment: Confirmed on VS2012. I have no idea, other than MS decided no one would use a snippet in a method call. They are generally for larger blocks of code.

Comment: Sure in this example I have used a small bit of code (I'm really lazy) but I was thinking about creating some snippets based on common (and significantly more complex) predicates but if snippets don't work in methods then I guess there's no point.

Comment: You could make those snippets as an actual function, then pass the function instead of an inline predicate. I don't see much recourse given the behavior I've seen.

Comment: yeah I was thinking about functions but I feel the predicate would be more readable and probably more flexible as there are sometimes subtle differences which could be easily edited into the predicate after applying a snippet. I suppose I was just hoping there would be some sort of configuration that could declare where a snippet could be used - anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Ctrl+K+X - takes a few more keypresses but it works inside methods' calls